# Payment options in Website itself

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, pci

Is there any extension(payment gateways, indian market) available to make the Payment in the website itself like in attached screen shot?  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Magento has the option for Authorize.NET, which will be a payment in your page. You just need to create your account here: http://www.authorize.net/

Another option is to use PayPal Pro account, which allows you to customize the payment form (instead of sending the user to PayPal website): https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro

Comment: Thanks. is Apache server compatible with PCI Compliance?

Comment: PayPal and Authorize.NET are PCI Compliance, so you will be good